# Winsorizing does not change the max value

Tags: python, scipy, outliers

I want to winsorize a variable (a column) in a dataframe. I found the `scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize` module and applied it to the respective variable. Some of the values of the variable are `NaN` which I want to ignore, hence I specifically specified it by defining the `nan_policy`.

Specifically, I did the following:

```
df['x_w'] = winsorize(df['x'], limits=[0.1, 0.1], nan_policy='omit')
```

However, what strikes me as suprprising are the results. The descriptive statistics of the non-winsorized variable are the following:

```
count    231002.000000
mean         89.959437
std        1005.742704
min      -99289.000000
25%          -2.749000
50%           1.621000
75%          24.001000
max      104821.000000
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

The descriptive statistics of the winsorized variable are as follows:

```
count    231002.000000
mean        111.408968
std         898.960866
min         -15.100000
25%          -2.749000
50%           1.621000
75%          24.001000
max      104821.000000
Name: x_w, dtype: float64
```

Clearly, the minimum value has changed. The maximum value, however, not. This can not be attributed to the fact that the maximum value occurs more than 10% of the time. It only occurs once. So essentially, the module only winsorizes the lower limit I specified. Why is that so and how do I tackle this issue?

Comment: according to the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html `limits` should be a tuple and you have a list. I wonder if it confuses the function. have you tried with a tuple?

Comment: Tried it out and it yields the same result.

Comment: you probably already checked all these but I would check (a) does the example from the doc works? (b) are you using the latest version of skipy? c) print and look all the values in `x` and `x_w` that are different? (d) calculate 5%th and 10% (upper) percentile manually and see if they changed?

Comment: (a) yes, (b) yes, (c) I haven't done that yet since my dataset is quite large. I just did it manually and it works perfectly fine. It has to be an issue associated with the module. I suspect it has something to do with the nan values.

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens when filtering nan values first? Just to understand if the problem is due to them or not